# Simple survey database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm creating a survey for visitors of my event.
However it's been a while since I created a database. So I need some help.

I found some solutions but they are way too extensive and that is something I don't need.

- Visitors need to stay anonymous but they can leave their email behind (seperate table `Emails` that isn't linked to anything atm).
- They have about 20 questions, some are open, some are one option(radio) and some are multiple options (checkboxes).
- The questions need to be reusable.

That's about it. I just don't know how to go beyond the many-to-many in the diagram.

Comment: Care to share the answer you found? Thanks.

Comment: I found it on stack overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540885/database-design-for-a-survey-system/5858666#answer-5858666

Answer (score 0):

Generally one row per respondent, and one column per question item.  A battery of ten check-all-that-apply questions would thus get ten columns (either boolean or integer).  Each open end gets a String field.  During analysis, you can get fancy and aggregate questions, stack repeated batteries of questions, etc. in SAS, SPSS or Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I found my answer on stackoverflow :)